# error while reading key value pair using javascript map to populate picker react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am trying to populate key value for picker element in react native from a kay, value pair. The app crashes when i try to pass the key-value list.

for example:(This does not work)

```
-- In the constructor
stateList: [{1:'Fortsworth'},{2:'Chicago'}],

--In the render()
this.state.stateList.map( (s, i) => {
  console.log('key='+i+',value='+s);
   return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />
});
```

However it only works if i pass array without key value pair. the below code works.

```
-- In the constructor
stateList: ['Fortsworth','Chicago'],

--In the render()
this.state.stateList.map( (s, i) => {
  console.log('key='+i+',value='+s);
   return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />
});
```

I need to pass the key as "1" and value as "Fortsworth" to the picker. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: both snippets are currently identical...

Comment: sorry..mybad..updated the question now..the statelist where is doesn't work is a map where as its an array in the second example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I know of to do this:

```
Object.keys(this.state.stateList).map(function(key) {
    let value = this.state.stateList[key];
    console.log('key=' + key + ',value=' + value);
    return <Picker.Item key={key} value={value} label={value} />
}
```

Essentially, you are looping over the list of keys and then pulling the value from your map using that key.

If anybody has a better solution, by all means provide it as an answer because I'm curious about this as well.

**EDIT**:

Sorry, just realized you have a list of map entries. For my answer, you would need `stateList` to be a map:

`stateList: {1:'Fortsworth', 2:'Chicago'}`

Comment: Thank you.. Iterating over keys helped. "let value = this.state.stateList[key]" throwed  "undefined is not an object error". I saved the list to another map object and retrieved the value from new map. That resolved the issue..

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea -

```
var states = [{'1': 'Fortsworth'}, {'2': 'Chicago'}];
var key = '';

states.map(s => {
  key = Object.keys(s)[0];
  console.log("key",key,"value",s[key]);
});
```